# Correlation coefficient of multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, correlation

I want to compute the correlation between the two arrays `a` and `b`; the shape of `a` and `b` is `(10, 2)`. I expect a correlation matrix with shape `(10, 10)` with values in the range `[-1, 1]`; a correlation value for every pair.

```
>>> a
array([[-1.22674504,  0.08136256],
       [ 1.95456381, -1.31209914],
       [ 0.29199221,  0.00573356],
       [ 0.66700798, -0.68239164],
       [-1.03723395, -0.15456914],
       [-0.52541249, -0.21180142],
       [-0.94584861, -0.81954194],
       [ 1.11044632,  2.02689438],
       [-0.12003807,  0.00595059],
       [-0.16873215,  1.06046219]])

>>> b
array([[-0.06960341,  0.01320213],
       [ 0.1108986 , -0.21290515],
       [ 0.01656714,  0.00093034],
       [ 0.03784489, -0.11072692],
       [-0.05885088, -0.02508085],
       [-0.029811  , -0.03436753],
       [-0.05366583, -0.13298134],
       [ 0.06300482,  0.32888998],
       [-0.00681075,  0.00096556],
       [-0.00957357,  0.17207378]])
```

I use `numpy.corrcoef(a, b)` and get a `(20, 20)` matrix, instead of `(10, 10)`.

```
>>> numpy.corrcoef(a, b)
array([[ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
         1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,
        -1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

One row is one observation with two values, how can I tell Python that it is 2-dimensional to compute the correlation? Why is every value exactly `-1` or `1`?

Comment: Have you read [the `corrcoef` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)?

Comment: What do you really want to do? `corrcoef` computes the coefficients of among the `rows`. So `np.all(np.corrcoef(a, b) == np.corrcoef(np.vstack((a, b)))) == True`

Comment: I want to compute the correlation for each pair of a and b. Get a 10x10 matrix, the entry_11 stands for element#1 of a (first row) and element#1 of b (first row). How this is possible? I tried the *scipy.signal.correlated2d(a,b)* but the result isn't as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You may need this code for `xcorr2` in `Matlab`, right?
This is `2-D cross-correlation`

```
import scipy.signal
print scipy.signal.correlate2d(a, b)
```

See : http://www.mathworks.co.kr/kr/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html

Also take look at this post: [Computing cross-correlation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991471/computing-cross-correlation-function)