# Cross-correlation (time-lag-correlation) with pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, correlation, cross-correlation

I have various time series, that I want to correlate - or rather, cross-correlate - with each other, to find out at which time lag the correlation factor is the greatest.

I found [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830840/python-cross-correlation) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991471/computing-cross-correlation-function) and answers/links discussing how to do it with numpy, but those would mean that I have to turn my dataframes into numpy arrays. And since my time series often cover different periods, I am afraid that I will run into chaos.

**Edit**

The issue I am having with all the numpy/scipy methods, is that they seem to lack awareness of the timeseries nature of my data. When I correlate a time series that starts in say 1940 with one that starts in 1970, pandas `corr` knows this, whereas `np.correlate` just produces a 1020 entries (length of the longer series) array full of nan.

The various Q's on this subject indicate that there should be a way to solve the different length issue, but so far, I have seen no indication on how to use it for specific time periods. I just need to shift by 12 months in increments of 1, for seeing the time of maximum correlation within one year.

**Edit2**

Some minimal sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfdates1 = pd.date_range('01/01/1980', '01/01/2000', freq = 'MS')
dfdata1 = (np.random.random_integers(-30,30,(len(dfdates1)))/10.0) #My real data is from measurements, but random between -3 and 3 is fitting
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dfdata1, index = dfdates1)
dfdates2 = pd.date_range('03/01/1990', '02/01/2013', freq = 'MS')
dfdata2 = (np.random.random_integers(-30,30,(len(dfdates2)))/10.0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dfdata2, index = dfdates2)
```

Due to various processing steps, those dfs end up changed into df that are indexed from 1940 to 2015. this should reproduce this:

```
bigdates = pd.date_range('01/01/1940', '01/01/2015', freq = 'MS')
big1 = pd.DataFrame(index = bigdates)
big2 = pd.DataFrame(index = bigdates)
big1 = pd.concat([big1, df1],axis = 1)
big2 = pd.concat([big2, df2],axis = 1)
```

This is what I get when I correlate with pandas and shift one dataset:

```
In [451]: corr_coeff_0 = big1[0].corr(big2[0])
In [452]: corr_coeff_0
Out[452]: 0.030543266378853299
In [453]: big2_shift = big2.shift(1)
In [454]: corr_coeff_1 = big1[0].corr(big2_shift[0])
In [455]: corr_coeff_1
Out[455]: 0.020788314779320523
```

And trying scipy:

```
In [456]: scicorr = scipy.signal.correlate(big1,big2,mode="full")
In [457]: scicorr
Out[457]: 
array([[ nan],
       [ nan],
       [ nan],
       ..., 
       [ nan],
       [ nan],
       [ nan]])
```

which according to `whos` is

```
scicorr               ndarray                       1801x1: 1801 elems, type `float64`, 14408 bytes
```

But I'd just like to have 12 entries.
**/Edit2**

The idea I have come up with, is to implement a time-lag-correlation myself, like so:

```
corr_coeff_0 = df1['Data'].corr(df2['Data'])
df1_1month = df1.shift(1)
corr_coeff_1 = df1_1month['Data'].corr(df2['Data'])
df1_6month = df1.shift(6)
corr_coeff_6 = df1_6month['Data'].corr(df2['Data'])
...and so on
```

But this is probably slow, and I am probably trying to reinvent the wheel here. **Edit** The above approach seems to work, and I have put it into a loop, to go through all 12 months of a year, but I still would prefer a built in method.

Comment: If you haven't seen these already, consider making use of the [`scipy.signal.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) and [`scipy.signal.correlate2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html). I would say that converting to numpy arrays is probably your best bet.

Comment: I have seen those, but I want to avoid going to numpy, because after this step, I would have to convert back to a dataframe, for further calculations. I guess I will try to reinvent the wheel, then…

Comment: That is a pretty common work flow as far as I know, converting to numpy and back. I don't see a need to hesitate in doing so. I would recommend writing your arrays to disk, so you don't repeat the conversions in your code. Checkout `pd.HDFStore` and `h5py`. If you feel up to reinventing the wheel, go for it.

Comment: Btw check into [pandas apply/ufunc object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html). You've probably found this already though. You can actually put a numpy function into the pandas apply object. So this could do the trick

Comment: Didn't know `series.apply`, thanks, that might come in handy later. The issue I am having with all the numpy/scipy methods, is that they seem to lack awareness of the timeseries nature of my data. When I correlate a time series that starts in say 1940 with one that starts in 1970, pandas `corr` knows this, whereas `np.correlate` just produces a 1020 entries array full of `nan`. I just need to shift for seeing the max correlation within one year.

Comment: Could you share some data in a pastebin or gist or any place of preference?

Comment: I have edited in some fake sample data, and how/why it is shaped like it is, so that it behaves and looks the same as my real data.

Comment: @JC_CL did you get anywhere with this? Also interested in a pandas based solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Funny that you ask… When I asked this question, I just went with the very rough thing I sketched in my question anyways, and then moved on, but as of today I have to do quite a lot of them, so I am working on something. The core is @DanielWatkins nice little piece of code below. If I get to something useful, I'll add it here.

Comment: @JC_CL , did you have a look at this package ? http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/index.html (if you don't mind leaving pandas for those calculations)

Answer (score 76):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a built in method that does *exactly* what you are asking. But if you look at the source code for the pandas Series method `autocorr`, you can see you've got the right idea:

```
def autocorr(self, lag=1):
    """
    Lag-N autocorrelation

    Parameters
    ----------
    lag : int, default 1
        Number of lags to apply before performing autocorrelation.

    Returns
    -------
    autocorr : float
    """
    return self.corr(self.shift(lag))
```

So a simple timelagged cross covariance function would be

```
def crosscorr(datax, datay, lag=0):
    """ Lag-N cross correlation. 
    Parameters
    ----------
    lag : int, default 0
    datax, datay : pandas.Series objects of equal length

    Returns
    ----------
    crosscorr : float
    """
    return datax.corr(datay.shift(lag))
```

Then if you wanted to look at the cross correlations at each month, you could do

```
 xcov_monthly = [crosscorr(datax, datay, lag=i) for i in range(12)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps quite a bit! Totally forgot that the built in autocorrelation is essentially a time lag correlation. I will see if I can work with that to produce some more useful output than just a list.

Comment: Just found this -- great answer!

Comment: When I apply this solution to my panda series it gives nan despite the two series are different

Answer (score 15):

To build up on Andre's answer - if you only care about (lagged) correlation to the target, but want to test various lags (e.g. to see which lag gives the highest correlations), you can do something like this:

```
lagged_correlation = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {x: [df[target].corr(df[x].shift(-t)) for t in range(max_lag)] for x in df.columns})
```

This way, each row corresponds to a different lag value, and each column corresponds to a different variable (one of them is the target itself, giving the autocorrelation).

Answer (score 13):

There is a **better approach**: You can create a function that ***shifted*** your dataframe first before calling the corr().

Get this dataframe like an example:

```
d = {'prcp': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.0], 'stp': [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> df
   prcp  stp
0   0.1  0.0
1   0.2  0.1
2   0.3  0.2
3   0.0  0.3
```

Your function to shift others columns (except the target):

```
def df_shifted(df, target=None, lag=0):
    if not lag and not target:
        return df       
    new = {}
    for c in df.columns:
        if c == target:
            new[c] = df[target]
        else:
            new[c] = df[c].shift(periods=lag)
    return  pd.DataFrame(data=new)
```

Supposing that your target is comparing the prcp (precipitation variable) with stp(atmospheric pressure)

If you do at the present will be:

```
>>> df.corr()
      prcp  stp
prcp   1.0 -0.2
stp   -0.2  1.0
```

But if you **shifted 1(one) period all other columns** and keep the **target** (prcp):

```
df_new = df_shifted(df, 'prcp', lag=-1)

>>> print df_new
   prcp  stp
0   0.1  0.1
1   0.2  0.2
2   0.3  0.3
3   0.0  NaN
```

Note that now the column stp is shift one up position at period, so if you call the corr(), will be:

```
>>> df_new.corr()
      prcp  stp
prcp   1.0  1.0
stp    1.0  1.0
```

So, you can do with lag -1, -2, -n!!