# How to find cross correlation between 2 data sets?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, correlation

I have 2 data sets that represents the availability of internet connection. I want to find cross correlation between this 2 sets.
My data is a two data frames :

First:

```
id  percent_availability    km
1   100               0.1
2   99.93437882       0.2
3   100               0.3
4   80                0.4
```

Second:

```
id  percent_availability    km
1   92.75525526         0.1
2   92.85714286         0.2
3   100                 0.3
4   20                  0.4
```

I transfere my data to an arrays and tried this methods: `signal.correlate(array,array1,mode='same') np.correlatenp.correlate(array,array1,mode='same')`

Also with dataframe I tried this `df1.corrwith(df, axis = 1)`

But the result is not that i expected.
What I try to find is a km where i have more or less the stable percentage availability but not the big jumps. What can I use for this task? I would like to have new array or dataframe with the kilomiters and similarity of the percentage availability.

Comment: Cannot quite comprehend what you are expecting. Have you checked out the solutions in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991471/computing-cross-correlation-function